# is there any solution for using an openVPN client in Azure Ubuntu virtual machine?

Tags: azure, openvpn

I have an openVPN config file for accessing lab network in oder to ingest data from an installed opcua server. Since my receiver is deplyed on an Ubuntu virtual machine on Azure, I decided to install the openvpn3 client and import  config file into it. However, everytime when I try running the client, the command window has no more response anymore after I input the password to this lab network.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your OpenVPN VPN and configure logging: openvpn3 log --log-level 6 --config custconfig.ovpn to investigate the problem

Comment: FYI this should be posted to SuperUser or ServerFault, not Stack Overflow (it's a networking/vpn question, not a programming question).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks for your reply. I will post the question there.